# Создать функцию-генератор из списка с изменяющимся инкрементом

Tags: python, генераторы

Подвох в том, что шаг должен быть 2 вариантов, которые должны чередоваться.
Например:

a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

step=1 or 2

generator(a,step)

вывод:
[1,2,4,5,7,8]

Важно также прописать условия, чтобы не выходить за границы списка. Я попробовал следущий код:

```
def generate_step(a, step):
    a = iter(a)
    step= 1 or 2
    it=iter(range(step))
    while True:
        for x in it:
            for dummy in range(step):
                try:
                    x = next(a)
                except StopIteration:
                    return
            yield x

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
b = generate_step(a, 2)
print(next(b))
```

Выводит только одно число, а не список

Comment: Интересно, а чего вы хотели добиться строчкой step = 1 or 2?

Comment: @strawdog только хотел написать то же самое )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас какой-то сумбур в коде (такое впечатление, что вы пытались собрать что-то одно из нескольких разных примеров). Все намного проще. Вот сама функция-генератор:

**UPDATE изменил на 2 чередующихся шага**

```
def generate_step(data: list, step1: int, step2: int):
    pos = 0
    step_count = True
    while pos < len(data):
        yield data[pos]
        if step_count:
            pos += step1
            step_count = False
        else:
            pos += step2
            step_count = True
```

А вот так выводим "ленивые" значения:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
b = (generate_step(a, 1, 2))
for value in b:
    print(value)
```

Вывод:

```
1
2
4
5
7
```

Comment: @Кирилл - обновил ответ

Comment: @Кирилл - У вас же 2 разных шага, которые должны задаваться? Или они всегда 1 и 2?

Comment: Так 2 разных или всегда 1 и 2? Какой тогда задается?

Comment: Тогда условию полностью удовлетворяет код в ответе - оба шага могут быть разными и задаются через аргументы при вызове функции

Comment: Тогда примите ответ )